# How does JavaScript pass values to a function expression within a declaration?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working through Head First JavaScript and have an example:

```js
 function addN(n) {
        var adder = function(x) {
                        return n + x;
                    };
        return adder;
    }
    
    var add2 = addN(2);
    
    console.log(add2(10));
    console.log(add2(100));
```

addN(2) gets assigned to add2, but nothing gets assigned to the x. However, upon running the code, the arguments 10 and 100 clearly get passed to the x. How does JavaScript know to pass the 10 and 100 to the x value?

Comment: In `add2(10)`, `10` is assigned to the variable `x`.

Comment: `add2 = function(x) { return 2 + x; };`

Comment: `addN` returns a function. Your question is like asking why nothing is assigned to the parameter `n` before the `var add2 = addN(2);` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var add2 = addN(2);
```

The variable `add2` is now effectively this:

```
function(x) {
    return 2 + x;
}
```

Because that function *itself* is the return value of `addN()`.  (Note that in JavaScript a function is a value that can be assigned to a variable like any other value.)

So when you further do this:

```
add2(10);
```

You are passing `10` to that function, so `x` will be `10`.